# adding to array from last element to the first one

Tags: javascript

I want some help to modify or create a function to do a simple task;

Here is my function:

```js
function arra(sum, length){
  var array = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    array.push(0);
  }
  
  //console.log(array) 
  for(let i = 0; i < sum; i++){
     array[i] ++
  }
  
  
  return array;
}

console.log(arra(0, 7));
console.log(arra(3, 7));
console.log(arra(7, 7));
console.log(arra(10, 7));
```

Here first, we create an array with a `length`, then we push `0` to each element of it. so the array will be :  `[0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0]`

Then based on the value of `sum` I want to add 1 from the last element of the `array`  to the beginning. The problem is I want to come back to the first element and keep adding 1 again if there is enough `sum`.

So if I execute this: `arra(3, 7);` I would have : `[0, 0, 0, 0 ,1 ,1, 1]`

if I execute this: `arra(7, 7)` I would have: `[1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1]`

But the problem is when I execute this: `arra(10, 7)` I get : `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN]` that is unexpected . I want to have : `[1, 1, 1, 1 ,2 ,2 ,2]`

Another problem is I can't add to array from the last element to the first...

**Edit**: How can fix it guys?

Comment: Your problem is here: `for(let i = 0; i < sum; i++){
     array[i] ++
  }`. You're indexing your array up to the value of `sum-1` instead of maximum of `length-1`. If you want to add to the array from the last element to the first, you can reverse your loop, `for (i = last; i>= 0; i--) ...`

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Can you please provide an answer...

Comment: It's not clear the order you want. Your test says: `[0, 0, 0, 0 ,1 ,1, 1]` your code says: `[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to "wrap around" you can index the array with the modulus of the length: `array[i%length]`. If you want to start at the other end, you can subtract from the `array[length - 1 - i % length]` — it wasn't clear to me which order you wanted, but the same idea works either way:

```js
function arra(sum, length){
  var array = Array(length).fill(0)   
  
  //console.log(array) 
  for(let i = 0; i < sum; i++){
     array[length - 1 - i % length] ++
  }
  
  
  return array;
}

console.log(arra(0, 7));
console.log(arra(3, 7));
console.log(arra(7, 7));
console.log(arra(10, 7));
```

Answer (score 4):

You get `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN]` this due to you initialize the array with the value of length, in this case you are calling `arra(10,7)`

```
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   array.push(0);
}
```

Here you are getting an array of 7 elements initialized to `0`

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Next you execute:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < sum; i++){
     array[i] ++
  }
```

You get 1 in the first 7 elements you initialized to 0, but the next 3 you get `NaN`

Why?

Due to `array[i]` is `undefined` and; `undefined` with the operator `++` coerces to `NaN`.

If you want to create a circular array:

```js
let array = null;

function circularArray(sum, length) {
  array = Array(length).fill(0);

  for (let count = 0; count < sum; count++) {
    array[count % array.length]++;
  }
}

circularArray(10, 7);

console.log(array.reverse());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I know where the problems are... But I need help to fix them... plus one...

Comment: The added function will add share the value of sum between the number of length items in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the min and max values for dispersing and get the length of the right part as well.

```js
function getArray(sum, length) {
    var max = Math.ceil(sum / length),
        min = Math.floor(sum / length),
        l = sum - min * length;

    return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => length - i > l ? min : max);
}

console.log(...getArray(0, 7));
console.log(...getArray(3, 7));
console.log(...getArray(7, 7));
console.log(...getArray(10, 7));
console.log(...getArray(20, 7));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just start from the end and reset back to end when you reach 1 the first element.

```js
function arra(sum, length){
  var array = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    array.push(0);
  }
 
  let x = length -1;

  while(sum > 0) {
    if(x < 0) { // go back to the end
      x = length -1;
    }
    array[x]++;
    x--;
    sum--;
  }
  
  return array;
}

console.log(arra(0, 7));
console.log(arra(3, 7));
console.log(arra(7, 7));
console.log(arra(10, 7));
```